# Exchange 2013 gets Quarantined

Tags: exchange

I have  users Exchange archive mailbox which gets Quarantined all the time.
 After some research, I found out how to release the archive mailbox from Quarantine, but after a few minutes the mailbox turns back to Quarantined state.
 I tried to export the archive to a pst file, but the time is not enough to export it before the mailbox turns back to Quarantined state.
 Can i turn off the Quarantine feature for the hole exchange 2013 mailbox server? So that i can export the corrupt archive to a pst file?
 Or any tools to fix the corrupt mailbox?  Any workaround here?

Thank you very much for any help!
Kind regards!

Comment: I would be grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

There's an issue if .net 4.6 is installed on Exchange 2013 servers (due a race condition).
If it's installed, you should remove it.

Here's a link to the related kb article:
[Mailboxes are quarantined and databases fail over unexpectedly in Exchange Server 2013 | Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3095369)